# uitableview first and last visible cell color change

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to to implement this function in `UITableView` for iPhone: always have only the FIRST and LAST VISIBLE cell have a different background color, say red, while color of the other cells remain white. and a smooth change during scrolling.
I have tried:

in `.m` file:

```
NSIndexPath *firstRow;
UITableViewCell* firstCell;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"tableCell";    
    tableCell *cell = (tableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"tableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    } 

    cell.nameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //cell.thumbnailImageView.image = image;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    NSArray *visible = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    firstRow = (NSIndexPath *)[visible objectAtIndex:0];
    firstCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:firstRow];
    firstCell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    NSLog(@"main visible cell's row: %i", firstRow.row);
    [tableView endUpdates];
    firstCell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];   
}
```

But the color wont update when scrolling back up.

Comment: more code required. post the code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Is there a reason you are calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in `willDisplayCell`? The datasource delegate calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath` on its own; you should not have to call it in that other method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it all in cellForRowAtIndexPath if you want.

```c
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *tableViewCellID = @"cellID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableViewCellID];
    if (!cell) 
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tableViewCellID];

    [[cell textLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"some sting %i", [indexPath row]]];


    NSArray *visibleCells = [tableView visibleCells];

    for (int i = 0; i < [visibleCells count]; i++) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [visibleCells objectAtIndex:i];
        if (i == 0 || i == [visibleCells count] - 1)
            [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        else 
            [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Try something like this

```
//Find the first row
if(indexPath.row == 0){
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

And to check for the last row, you should reuse the code you made for

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Comment: that changes the colour of the first cell roll. My intention is to have the first and last ON SCREEN cell to be red. kind of like an animation.